# I'm trying to take a tutorial for discord.js... but It showed me an error known as "Unknown application"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I tried to take a tutorial for discord.js.

[This is the tutorial!](https://discordjs.guide/creating-your-bot/creating-commands.html#command-deployment-script)

But it showed me an error, "DiscordAPIError[10002]: Unknown Application"

I think the error is related for my clientID or applicationID to be wrong.. But I verified everything and its right!

Heres my code:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder, Routes } = require('discord.js');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('ping').setDescription('Replies with pong!'),
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('server').setDescription('Replies with server 
info!'),
new SlashCommandBuilder().setName('user').setDescription('Replies with user info!'),
]
.map(command => command.toJSON());

const rest = new REST({ version: '10' }).setToken(token);

rest.put(Routes.applicationGuildCommands(myclientidofc, myguildid), { 
body: commands })
.then(() => console.log('Successfully registered application commands.'))
.catch(console.error);
```

Anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have `clientId` and a `guildId` variables coming from your `config.json` file. But in your `Routes.applicationGuildCommands()` function call, you pass `myclientidofc` and `myguildid` variables that don't seem to exists. Can you try using `clientId` and a `guildId` instead?

Comment: i did the same thing.... just in here i changed it.

Comment: basically i did the same thing what u said but i changed it here in the code

Comment: Do you have the right version of Discord.js? (check your `package.json` file > dependencies, it should be 14.0.0 or higher) 

The right version of node? (type `node -v` in your terminal, it shoud be 16.0.0 or higher) 

Finally, does your `config.js` have great values? Do you use double quotes `""` around them?

Comment: Yeah! All my versions are correct! My discord.js version is 14.1.1 and node version is 16.15.1 !

Comment: Yup! I use double quatation marks for config.json .

Comment: Do you use this `clientId` (https://discord.com/developers/applications/xxxxxxxxxx/oauth2/general) and guildId from your target server?

Comment: yup i use it... i used the client id and guild id